# Windows Identity Foundation different authentication for site section

Tags: security, wif

I'm new to WIF - sorry in advance if my questions seems to be very basic...

I have a 1 WebSite lets say localhost that require username/password authentication. Access to //localhost/ForSecuredClientsOnly should require **only** client certificate to access the site.

AFAIK client certificates authenticaion is handled by IIS, how should I handle this problem if I want to use STS?

**My ideas:**

1. Use 1 STS, set IIS to Accept certificate (not to require) and read certificate in STS and figure out whether user can access the resource. 
   I was reading through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359105(v=PandP.10).aspx and
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2010/04/03/wif-and-mvc-how-it-works.aspx but when I'm already logged in to //localhost and try to access //localhost/ForSecuredClientsOnly STS thinks that I'm a valid user.

   I'm returning new Redirect result from ForSecuredClientsOnly (path from `SignInRequestMessage`, since user does not belongs to group `X`) but the realm is always: //localhost/ (probably it's expected behaviour and reason why user is authenticated ...)
2. Use 2 STSs and move //localhost/ForSecuredClientsOnly to //securedClients.localhost. I don't really like idea of having 2 STSs though
3. Have 1 STS and create to websites pointing to the same STS. 
   I hope that then in STS I'll see that sign-in request is going from different realm and then perform either username/password of client certificate authentication?
    I would also prefer not to use that option since it's not ideal if I need to create new website per section of the site that requires different authentication.

**Questions:**

1. I would like to make idea number 1 working but how can I pass different realm depending on site subsection, I see that I can set `HomeRealm` property on `SignInRequestMessage` but how can I later read it in STS? (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `true` in STS if I already logged in to //localhost).
   Should I be using `HomeRealm` at all to distinguish between site sections?
2. If you have ideas what's the best approach to read and validate client certificate in STS please let me know. 
   Currently I'm thinking that I should check whether certificate Thumbnail is one of the certificates that I'm allowing - store collection on client certificate Thumbnails in database?

I appreciate all your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be worth looking at the [Starter STS](http://startersts.codeplex.com/) community project at Codeplex.